# Проблема с цикличностью в @OneToMAny. При добавлении данных в список происходит циклическая зависимость и переполняется стек. Как поправить?

Tags: one-to-many

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class PostalShipment {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private ShipmentType type;
        private String recipientIndex;
        private String recipientAddress;
        private String recipientNae;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shipment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<ShipmentHistory> history = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public void addHistory(ShipmentHistory shipmentHistory){
            history.add(shipmentHistory);
            shipmentHistory.setShipment(this);
        }
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class ShipmentHistory {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private LocalDateTime timestamp;
        private String fromPostOffice;
        private String toPostOffice;
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "shipment_id")
        private PostalShipment shipment;
    }
    
// Это в сервисе.
      public PostalShipment registerShipment(PostalShipment postalShipment) {
            ShipmentHistory history = new ShipmentHistory();
            history.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
            history.setFromPostOffice(null);
            history.setToPostOffice(postalShipment.getRecipientIndex());
            postalShipment.addHistory(history);
            return postalShipmentRepository.save(postalShipment);
        }
    }
```